# HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I am using hibernate Hibernate-Version: 3.2.5.ga.Along with this I am using gwt2.3 version.
Now when I tried to upgrade hibernate version, I am getting error.I have downloaded hibernate 3.6.7 final version and replaced it old jar file in.but when I run application on first server hit it is giving below error.If I replace new jar with old jar then there is no issue...but for new jar it is giving error.
help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.hibernate.util.HibernateFactory.configureSessionFactory(HibernateFactory.java:107)
at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.hibernate.util.HibernateFactory.buildIfNeeded(HibernateFactory.java:42)
at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.model.dao.AbstractDao.<init>(AbstractDao.java:20)
at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.model.dao.UserDetailsDao.<init>(UserDetailsDao.java:24)
at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.facade.UserFacade.doLogin(UserFacade.java:753)
at com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.facade.UserFacade.workflowMethodCaller(UserFacade.java:822)
at com.nextenders.server.guice.actions.handlers.LoginCallerActionHandler.execute(LoginCallerActionHandler.java:61)
at com.nextenders.server.guice.actions.handlers.LoginCallerActionHandler.execute(LoginCallerActionHandler.java:1)
at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.doExecute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:153)
at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:111)
at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 19):

It can't acceess  Bean Validation Framework (BeanValidationActivator) Please make sure that the following dependency are in class path or in pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 10):

By default Hibernate validator is set to auto, meaning if there is a validator in the classpath it will try to use it. GWT 2.3 and newer versions include the validation api inside the gwt-servlet.jar, so Hibernate ends up with a parcial validator and fails. If you don't want to use Hibernate Validation just turn it off in your properties (hibernate.cfg.xml, hibernate.properties or programatically).

Simply set `javax.persistence.validation.mode` to `none`

Answer (score 6):

By default Hibernate's validator is set to true, meaning if there is a validator in the classpath it will try to use it. GWT 2.3 and newer versions include the validation api inside the gwt-servlet.jar, so Hibernate ends up with a parcial validator and fails. If you don't want to use Hibernate Validation just turn it off in your properties (hibernate.cfg.xml, hibernate.properties or programatically).

for example: in hibernate.cfg.xml add the hibernate validation mode to none

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem but then I added the below dependency and it worked fine.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But use the correct version. When I used 5.1.3.Final, it kept on failing but then I changed the version to 4.2.0.Final and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing both the hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar & validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1.- You could disable the Hibernate Validation:

```
setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "NONE");
```

2.- Add these dependencies, if you don't use maven then download the jars and add to your artifact manually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- No required in JBoss but for test -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- No required in JBoss but for test -->
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are helpful for Maven. I'm using Gradle and I found that all I needed to do was add:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '4.2.0.Final'
```

And the error disappeared and my app functioned properly.
I did not need to exclude the javax validation jar or change the persistence validation mode as the other answers mentioned.